# I have to display a list of tracks GROUPED BY Album in WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox, group-by

Now I am aware that I probably need to use a ListBox and can use the GroupStyle stuff which completely 100% fits my needs.  Only thing is that I've been told that:

*"Whenever a "GroupStyle" is set on the control, the panel that layouts the items changes from VirtualizingStackPanel to StackPanel (this is a hack in MS code)..."*

I will need to display up to 2000 tracks using this mecahnism:

1) Does this bug still exist?

2) Is this something to worry about for up to 2000 tracks? (More like an average of 50-100)

Also, the group by will not be changed by the user.  The tracks will be grouped the same way throughout the duration of the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `ListBox` still stops virtualisation of items when groups are applied.

Whether 2000 items would perform adequately will depend upon the complexity of the template applied to each item.  I have a `ListBox` with a relatively simple template (about 8 `TextBlock`s in a horizontal `StackPanel`) and performance starts to degrade at around 1500 items with grouping applied.  It also seems to depend upon the number of groups into which the items are aggregated, where a greater number of groups results in less performance.  This is especially noticeable when scrolling for some reason.

`ListBox` makes dynamic grouping very easy, but if you're usually going to be grouping by album then it might be better to set the `ItemsSource` of your `ItemsControl` (maybe a `ListBox`) to be a collection of `Album` objects, each of which has a `Tracks` property that is itself a collection of `Track` objects.  Assuming this, I see two options:

1. Use nested `ItemsControls` in the `Album` `DataTemplate`
2. Use a `HeaderedItemsControl` such as `TreeView` with a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`

In option one, you have to manage the selection manually.  You could, in the simplest implementation, have the ability to select albums and tracks separately; potentially having a track selected that didn't belong to the selected album.  You may be able to do without selection of an album as this isn't a concept present in the track-list view of other media players I can think of.

Solution one also has implications for keyboard navigation from the last track of one album to the first track of the next album.

Assuming the following code:

```
public class Album
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
}

public class Track
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

_tracks.ItemsSource = new[] {
    new Album { 
        Title = "Album 1",
        Tracks = new ObservableCollection<Track> {
            new Track { Title = "Track 1" },
            new Track { Title = "Track 2" }
        }
    },
    new Album { 
        Title = "Album 2",
        Tracks = new ObservableCollection<Track> {
            new Track { Title = "Track 1" },
            new Track { Title = "Track 2" }
        }
    }
};
```

Here's some code that demonstrates option one:

```
<ListBox x:Name="_tracks">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Track}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Album}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tracks}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Change the outer `ListBox` to an `ItemsControl` to alleviate the selection issue, as discussed.  You'll have to make it look pretty though as the above looks pretty ugly.

Option two could be defined like this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="_tracks2">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Track}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Album}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tracks}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

`ListView` supports opt-in UI virtualisation as of 3.5SP1 via the XAML attribute:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
```

Bea Stollnitz has [three](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=42) [great](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=43) [posts](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=45) on this topic, though as she points out they're out of date since SP1.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug...it's by design!

Comment: Agreed, you can't really allow rich data templating when virtualizing w/group by.